# WSO2 API Manager under 2 Gb memory minimum requirement possible by changing runtime setup?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can I run WSO2 API Manager UNDER the 2 Gb memory minimum requirement if I can switch off features that I don't need?
My server is limited to 1 GB. I am wondering if I can run WSO2 API Manager with lower memory footprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think WSO2 has tested this scenario. However, this depends on your environment. For a production environment, it's not a good idea to go below the recommended numbers. If it's for a dev environment, you can have a try to remove unwanted features.

By the way, have you tried [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/)? Both cloud and standalone server use the same core and technologies.  Since you're are having hardware limitations in your local environment, I suggest you try WSo2 cloud which offers a free tier too.